# Update listviewitems using textboxes in another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, textbox

I have Form1(main form) where I load in a ListView a list of Products created in Form2. I created a context menu strip that when i select a row from the listView, and choose the Edit option in that context menu, Form2 shows up, and all the textboxes I use to create the Products are completed with the values contained in the row I selected in ListView.

What I want to do is to be able to edit one or more values of the row selected using the textBoxes in the Form2, and then send the updated list of Products back to Form1 to be displayed without changing the order of the rows like it would have if I first deleted the row, then add it again, but updated.

Thanks. That's what I achieved so far in Form2:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2_nume.Text == "") errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2_nume, "Introduceti numele");
            else if (textBox3_units.Text == "") errorProvider1.SetError(textBox3_units, "Introduceti units");
            else if (textBox4_price.Text == "") errorProvider1.SetError(textBox4_price, "enter price");
            else if (comboBox1_supID.Text == "") errorProvider1.SetError(comboBox1_supID, "Select sup id");
            else
                try
                {
                   // Product pSelected;
                    foreach (Product p in prodList)
                    {
                        if (p.Id == Convert.ToInt32(textBox1__id.Text))
                        {
                           // p.Id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1__id.Text);
                            p.Nume = textBox2_nume.Text;
                            p.Units = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3_units.Text);
                            p.Price = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4_price.Text);
                            p.SupplierId = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1_supID.Text);
                        }

                    }      

                    MessageBox.Show("Produs modificat cu succes"); 
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    textBox1__id.Clear();
                    textBox2_nume.Clear();
                    textBox4_price.Clear();
                    textBox3_units.Clear();
                    errorProvider1.Clear();
                    comboBox1_supID.ResetText();
                }


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.productlist = prodList;

            frm.Show();
        }
```

And this is how I populate the listView in Form1 using the list of Products created in Form2 and then sent to Form1:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Product p in productlist)
            {

                ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem(p.Id.ToString());
                itm.SubItems.Add(p.Nume);
                itm.SubItems.Add(p.Units.ToString());
                itm.SubItems.Add(p.Price.ToString());
                itm.SubItems.Add(p.SupplierId.ToString());

                listView1.Items.Add(itm);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that in `Form2` you are setting `textBox1__id` 's text as per selected item in list view. and also it is not editable (if it is, you must set it not editable).

**product list is accessible at both form, make sure you have common (shared) copy of product list between both forms. else your logic will not work.**

now you can create an event say `ItemUpdated` in `Form2`, and whenever in form 2 you are updating values of selected item, you raise that event. This event will be listened by your main form (`Form1`), on the handler method of that event you call logic of repopulating the list view.

so while creating an instance of `Form2` and calling `.Show()` for that, you should subscribe it's event. like below.

And also in form2, you pass object of Form1, so you dont have to create new instance of Form1 while moving back from Form2 to Form1.

in Form1, while calling `Form2`

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ItemUpdated += frm_ItemUpdated;
frm.Show(this); 
this.Hide();
```

and for that you must have `frm_ItemUpdated` method in Form 1.

```
public void frm_ItemUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call your logic to updated list view
}
```

while at `Form2`

constrocutor

```
public event EventHandler ItemUpdated;
private Form1 form1;
private List<Product> prodList;
public Form2(Form1 sender, List<Product> productList)
{
    this.form1 = sender;
    this.prodList = productList; 
    //and other things what you are doing in contructor
}
```

button3 's logic on Form2 is proper, just add event updating.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //logic whatever you are doing currently

        //you should not be requred to assign updated prod list back
        //as it is referece type and change in this prodList, will refrect in main prodlist
        //frm1.productlist = prodList;

        if(ItemUpdated != null)
            ItemUpdated(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

and in button 2, go back on Form1

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this will show the same Form1, from which we came to Form2
        frm1.Show(); 
    }
```

Comment: well, but in ItemUpdated in Form1 what should I call from Form2 to update my item in listview?

Comment: @HatzJon have you tried this changes. see when you raise an event from Form2, which Form1 is listening, Form2 doesn't have to do anything more than that.. now it is Form1's duty to call logic to do stuff.. here in this case.. whatever you are doing in `button2_Click` in Form1, put that in a method (int form 1 only), and call that method from `frm_ItemUpdated` too (which is in Form1 too)